# Deprecated the ListenerInterface, turn your listeners into callables instead

Tags: symfony, symfony4

Deprecated the ListenerInterface, turn your listeners into callables instead

Question related to Symfony 4.3
after this update, they update these security updates.
1.Deprecated the ListenerInterface, turn your listeners into callables instead

How can i use callbacks with an interface?

Comment: Might want to add just a few more details to your question.  Maybe copy/paste (into your question) the complete deprecation message.  Or maybe explain what callbacks have to do with an interface?  I suspect you are not actually using the Symfony framework but rather something that uses some Symfony components.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\ListenerInterface;

class MyListener implements ListenerInterface
{
    public function handle(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        // code
    }
}
```

Turn listeners into callables. Change your code to:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\RequestEvent;

class MyListener
{
    public function __invoke(RequestEvent $event)
    {
        // code
    }
}
```

Then symfony or you can call `Mylistener` as a function

```
$myListener = new MyListener();
$myListener($event);
```